# Cannot get this Regex - \[pbrc:tl:[^]]*ad*\] - to work?

Tags: regex

I have the following possible text strings:

```
[pbrc:tl:ad,xch]
[pbrc:tl:xch,ad,xyy]
[pbrc:tl:xch, xx, ad]
```

I need to ensure that "pbrc:tl:" and "ad" (following the colon, somewhere but before the "]" is searched. All of the above examples should return true. I am currently using the following Regex which is failing.

```
\[pbrc:tl:[^]]*ad*\]
```

I would appreciate a correction to my Regex.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT

These need to return false:

```
[pbrc:st:ad]
[pbrc:tl:abc]
```

I will check whether this is true for the provided solutions. First does not I believe.

Comment: [`\[pbrc:tl:.*?ad.*?\]`](https://regex101.com/r/rK8mA8/1) **Edit:** This will only work for the given inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ad*`  matches `a` and zero or more `d` symbols. You need to allow any number of characters other than `]` before the final `]`, thus, replace the last `*` with `[^]]*`:

```
\[pbrc:tl:[^]]*ad[^]]*]
                 ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jU3qB1/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `pbrc:tl:` - literal text `pbrc:tl:`
- `[^]]*`  - zero or more characters other than `]` (in some regex flavors, the `]` inside *must* be escaped, e.g. in JavaScript, or ICU)
- `ad`  - a literal text `ad`
- `[^]]*` -  zero or more characters other than `]`
- `]` -a literal `]` (may be escaped, in most languages, it does not need escaping when outside a character class).

Answer (score 0):

you miss after **ad**

```
\[pbrc:tl:[^]]*ad[^]]*\]
```